# Run exe in windows container using python

Tags: python, docker, executable, windows-container

I am working on executing an exe file (notepad.exe) inside windows container using python.

I have copied these in my container:

exe file

dockerfile that calls python script

python script that runs exe

When I build and run these, Its not showing any error. This is the python code I am executing.

```
import os
print(“working”)
os.startfile(“notepad.exe”)
print(“successful”)
```

[Build and Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVqzS.png)

The print commands are successful. As notepad is not opening, I don't know whether it is executing or not. Actually, I want to execute an exe file and take the memory dump of Windows container.

Can you please tell me what to do for getting the memory dump in windows container? Also,how will I know that the exe is executing or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to run

```
import os
os.startfile("C:\Users\Documents and Settings\model\notepad.exe")
```

How to start

```
import sys, string, os, arcgisscripting
os.system("C:\Users\Documents and Settings\model\notepad.exe")
```

If you want to make an executable

```
pip install pyinstaller

cd PathOfFile

pyinstaller --onefile -w randomname.py
```

Comment: Still,it's not working. Now, I am not getting the output of print commands as well.

Comment: Print commands are not outputting as my code does not consist of print commands. But ill try to recreate your problem and let you know

Comment: Thank you. Btw, I have added print commands in your program and then only, I tried.